# Pop method for linked list behaves unexpectedly

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have two different linked lists, and I try to pop one node from the first linked list and to to the second linked list. My goal when calling the pop function (`pop(Node * head)`) is to update the new head and return to the popped node. However, what happens is that it turns to the popped node but the passed `Node * head` points to the popped element. Hence I cannot proceed. What is my problem with this function? I'm probably messing up with the pointers

```
Node * pop(Node * head)
{
    Node * temp = head;
    long val = temp -> value; //store the value before deallocating

    head = head -> next;
    free(temp);
    return createNode(val);
}

//Code snippet where I call the pop function
if (currNode == NULL) {
                headSublistPointers -> node = pop(tmpHeadOrigArr);
            } else {
                while (currNode -> next != NULL) {
                    currNode = currNode -> next; //go until the end of the linked list
                }
                currNode -> next = pop(tmpHeadOrigArr);
            }
```

Comment: `headSublistPointers -> node = pop(tmpHeadOrigArr);` This is just going to keep making you point at the original head since your implementation of pop returns the poped node

Comment: [How do I modify a pointer that has been passed into a function in C?](//stackoverflow.com/a/766905)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function

```
Node * pop(Node * head)
{
    Node * temp = head;
    long val = temp -> value; //store the value before deallocating

    head = head -> next;
    free(temp);
    return createNode(val);
}
```

does not make sense.

For starters the head shall be passed by reference

```
Node * pop(Node **head);
```

and secondly instead of freeing the popped node you could just return it setiing its data member next to NULL. Also in general the head node can be equal to NULL.

The function can look like

```
Node * pop( Node **head ) 
{
    Node *current = *head;

    if ( *head != NULL )
    {
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        current->next = NULL;
    }

    return current;
}
```